# Partial vs Total Derivative (Basic)

Tags: calculus

I am trying to understand the difference between a partial derivative and a total derivative when one component is defined as a function of another

If I have a function such as $f(x,y(x)) = x+y$

and $y(x) = x^2$

Is it true that the total derivative with respect to $x$ is $1 + 2x$

While the partial with respect to $x$ is $1$

Thanks

Comment: I believe this post answers your question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174270/what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-a-derivative-and-a-total-derivative

Answer (score 1):

$f(x,y)=x+y$

To find out the partial derivative with respect to $x$, we treat $y$ as a constant, and differentiate the whole expression w.r.t. $x$.

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{dx}{dx}=1$$

Total derivative is given by:

$$df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx +\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy$$

So
$$\frac{df}{dx}=1+ 1*\frac{dy}{dx}=1+2x$$