# (Why) can we treat a function of a variable as another independent variable?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, numerical-methods, jacobian, numerical-calculus

I'm currently reading my numerical analysis textbook and something's bugging me. To get into it, let's take a look at the following differential equation;

$$u'(x) = f(x, u(x))$$

In order to determine the stability of the equation, one may calculate the Jacobian,

$$J(x, u(x)) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}|_{(x, u(x))}$$

Here is a specific differential equation:

$$u'(x) = -\alpha(u(x) - sin(x)) + cos(x)$$

For which the Jacobian is

$$J(x, u(x)) = -\alpha$$

Basically, we treated both $sin(x)$ and $cos(x)$ as constants with respect to $u$, but I don't really understand why. Most of the time, when we take a derivative the variables are independant, which is not the case here as they both depend on the same variable $x$.

This means that the "rate of change of $sin(x)$ with respect to $u(x)$" is zero, but the value of $u(x)$ only changes if the value of x itself changes, so shouldn't the value of $sin(x)$ change aswell?

Thank you!

Comment: "Most of the time, when we take a derivative the variables are independant, which is not the case here as they both depend on the same variable x."  I don't understand.  When you take the derivative of a function with one variable there is only one variable and you *don't* treat the variable**s** as independent.  As $\sin$ and $cos$ are both dependent on one variable this is a function with one variable.  Can you give an example of a case where "take a derivative the variables are independant"

Comment: "This means that the "rate of change of sin(x) with respect to u(x)" is zero, but the value of u(x) only changes if the value of x itself changes, so shouldn't the value of sin(x) change as well?"  Of course it does.  But that is *with respect to $x$* and not with respect to $u(x)$.

Comment: @fleablood Thanks for your answers, I thought because both sin(x) and u(x) depend on x, that sin(x) would also depend on u(x) but as I read this it makes sense that these two functions are not linked to each other although they both depend on the same variable

Comment: When you compute the linear expansion, you do it for the function $f:\Bbb R^{1+n}\to\Bbb R^n$. You get $f(x,u)\approx f(x, u_0)+∂_uf(x,u_0)(u-u_0)$. Then you approximate the ODE $u'(x)=f(x,u(x))$ with the linearization of the right side. Further using $u=u_0+v$, this reads as $v'(x)=f(x,u_0)+∂_uf(x,u_0)v(x)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a difference between the partial derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and the total derivative $\frac{d}{dx}$. For example, if we have variables $(u,x)$ and the equation $f=f(x,u(x))=x^2+u^3$ and we take the partial derivative we get $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=2x$ but if we take the total derivative we get $\frac{d f}{dx}=2x+3u^2\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$, applying the chain rule. This distintion is a key point in classical mechanics for example and captures essentially what you are asking.

See: [What exactly is the difference between a derivative and a total derivative?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174270/what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-a-derivative-and-a-total-derivative)

Answer (score 2):

To make things simpler, imagine a very simple [autonomous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(mathematics)) dynamical system

$$
\frac{{\rm d}u}{{\rm d}x} = \alpha (u - u_0) \tag{1}
$$

for some constants $\alpha$ and $u_0$. The solutions to this system are of the form

$$
u(x) - u_0 = ce^{\alpha x} \tag{2}
$$

The interesting thing to note here is that if $\alpha > 0$ then the distance between $u(x)$ and $u_0$ grows exponentially with increasing $x$, so $u = u_0$ is said to be unstable. Whereas if $\alpha < 0$ the opposite occurs, and the distance between $u$ and $u_0$ shrinks with increasing $x$, in this case $u = u_0$ is stable.

Now let's make things a bit more general. Imagine a system of the form

$$
\frac{{\rm d}u}{{\rm d}x} = f(u) \tag{3}
$$

and suppose there exists a point $u_0$ such that $f(u_0) = 0$ (like in Eq. (1)), if you want to understand the local stability of (3) you could Taylor expand $f$ around $u_0$

$$
f(u) = f(u_0) + \left.\frac{{\rm d}f}{{\rm d}u}\right|_{u = u_0}(u - u_0) + \cdots \tag{4}
$$

Remember that $f(u_0) = 0$, so at first order $f(u)\approx f'(u_0)(u - u_0)$, and Eq. (3)

$$
\frac{{\rm d}u}{{\rm d}x} \approx \underbrace{f'(u_0)}_{\alpha}(u- u_0) \tag{5}
$$

Now compare this with Eq. (1) and you realize that in order to understand the stability of the system around the point $u_0$ you need to know the value of $f'(u_0) $ a.k.a the Jacobian. There's a lot of caveats here you should be aware of, probably your text talks about them (e.g. what happens if $f'(u_0) = 0$, ...)

---

**EDIT**

Now imagine a system in two dimensions, something like

$$
\frac{{\rm d}u}{{\rm d}x} = f(u, v) ~~~~ \frac{{\rm d}v}{{\rm d}x} = g(u, v)\tag{6}
$$

You can define vectors ${\bf z} = {u \choose v}$ and ${\bf F} = {f \choose g}$ so that the system above can be written as

$$
\frac{{\rm d}{\bf z}}{{\rm d}x} = {\bf F}({\bf z}) \tag{7}
$$

In this case nothing changes much, you can repeat the same analysis as in the first part and realize that the stability of the system around a point ${\bf z} = {\bf z}_0$ is given by the eigenvalues of the Jacobian evaluated at that location. And as before we require that $\color{blue}{{\bf F}({\bf z}_0) = 0}$. I highlight this condition because it will become important later.

Now to the final part. Instead of an autonomous system, consider a system of the form

$$
\frac{{\rm d}u}{{\rm d}x} = f(x, u) \tag{8}
$$

You could rename $v = x$ (that is, create a new state), and note that

$$
\frac{{\rm d}u}{{\rm d}x} = f(u, v) ~~~~ \frac{{\rm d}v}{{\rm d}x} = 1 \tag{9}
$$

So in theory you could repeat the same analysis all over again, *but*, you can see from this that the resulting field ${\bf F}$ never vanishes (that is, the blue expression above can never be satisfied)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! It's exactly the stuff I'm reading right now. However my question was not so much about stability but more about what it meant to take the derivative of sin(x) and cos(x) with respect to u

Comment: @FredV Sorry, I extended my answer, hopefully it makes more sense now. Otherwise I will gladly delete it