# $\frac {\partial} {\partial y'}\bigg(\frac {dF}{dx}\bigg)$

Tags: partial-derivative

In a part about the Euler - Langrange equation it is said that for a function $F(x,y,y')$

$$ \frac {dF}{dx} = \frac {\partial F}{\partial x}+ \frac {\partial F}{\partial y}y'+ \frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}y''$$

Now we wish to apply this to:

$$\frac {\partial} {\partial y'}\bigg(\frac {dF}{dx}\bigg)$$

Hence in my opinion: 
$$\frac {\partial} {\partial y'}\bigg(\frac {\partial F}{\partial x}+ \frac {\partial F}{\partial y}y'+ \frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}y''\bigg)$$

Which tmho would become:

$$\frac {\partial^2F}{\partial x\partial y'}+\frac {\partial^2F}{\partial y\partial y'}y'+\frac {\partial^2F}{\partial y'^2}y''$$

But the answer tells me: 
$$\frac {\partial^2F}{\partial x\partial y'}+\frac {\partial^2F}{\partial y\partial y'}y'+\frac {\partial^2F}{\partial y'^2}y''+\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}$$

Could somebody explain where I am going wrong? I can't see where the last fraction $\frac {\partial F}{\partial y}$ comes from...

Comment: Product rule on the middle term $\frac{\partial}{\partial y'} (\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}y') =  (\frac{\partial}{\partial y'}\frac{\partial F}{\partial y})y' +  (\frac{\partial F}{\partial y})\underbrace{\frac{\partial}{\partial y'}y'}_{=1}$

Comment: I understand what you are doing, but applied to the last term:$\frac{\partial}{\partial y'} (\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}y'') =  (\frac{\partial}{\partial y'}\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'})y'' +  (\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}) {\frac{\partial}{\partial y'}y''}$.Which is not correct I think

Comment: Does the last term vanish? Because it is equal to zero?

Comment: Remember you are taking a PARTIAL derivative $\frac{\partial }{\partial y'}$ NOT a full derivative like you did for $\frac{d}{dx}$, therefor you are holding $x$ and $y''$ constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to a misinterpretation of the partial derivative and full derivative. Computationally, the calculation would be

\begin{align}\frac {\partial} {\partial y'}\bigg(\frac {dF}{dx}\bigg)&=\frac {\partial} {\partial y'}\bigg(\frac {\partial F}{\partial x}+ \frac {\partial F}{\partial y}y'+ \frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}y''\bigg) \\&=
\frac {\partial} {\partial y'}\bigg(\frac {\partial F}{\partial x}\bigg)+\frac {\partial} {\partial y'}\bigg( \frac {\partial F}{\partial y}y'\bigg)+\frac {\partial} {\partial y'}\bigg(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}y''\bigg) \\&=
\frac {\partial^2F}{\partial x\partial y'}+\bigg(\frac {\partial^2F}{\partial y\partial y'}y'+\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\bigg)+\frac {\partial^2F}{\partial y'^2}y''
\end{align}

where the last equality is true because

$$\frac {\partial} {\partial y'}\bigg( \frac {\partial F}{\partial y}y'\bigg)=\frac {\partial^2F}{\partial y\partial y'}y'+\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\tag{1}$$
$$\frac {\partial} {\partial y'}\bigg(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}y''\bigg)=\frac {\partial^2F}{\partial y'^2}y''\tag{2}$$

As noted in the comments, $(1)$ follows from a direct application of the product rule. However, $(2)$ follows from the definition of the partial derivative. When you defined $F=F(x,y,y')$ as a function of $x,y,y'$ and then wrote

$$ \frac {dF}{dx} = \frac {\partial F}{\partial x}+ \frac {\partial F}{\partial y}y'+ \frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}y''\tag{3}$$

you took the full derivative of $\frac {dF}{dx}$. However

$$\frac {\partial} {\partial y'}\bigg(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}y''\bigg)$$

isn't a full derivative. It is a partial derivative in which you assume that both $x$ and $y''$ are fixed (i.e. constants). This is why $(2)$ isn't

$$\frac {\partial} {\partial y'}\bigg(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}y''\bigg)=\frac {\partial^2F}{\partial y'^2}y''+ \bigg(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}\bigg)\frac {\partial} {\partial y'} y''$$

A good summary of the difference between the two is shown inside [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174270/what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-a-derivative-and-a-total-derivative). The key difference is that when you take a partial derivative, you operate under a sort of assumption that you hold one variable fixed while the other changes. When computing a total derivative, you no longer have this assumption. As shown inside $(3)$, changes in one variable can affect the other two variables.

Comment: Remark: Some people use total derivative while other people say full derivative. I have always thought that total derivative means full derivative.